# take long time loading image in firefox using very simple image gallery plugin for joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla1.5

I have some problem using very simple image gallery plugin for joomla 1.5.It takes long time to load images when click on the thumbnail images.I have enabled the use javascript features.
How can I reduce the loading time of the big images when click on the thumbnail images?I have to enabled the "use javascript" option as that is the requirement.

Comment: You should reduce the size of each image, I don't think the javascript is responsible

Answer (score 0):

hope this link will help you:

> http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/photo-gallery/11426

Use this Photo Gallery Plugin which is very effective,

on the other hand you talked about to reduce the loading time, i don't know if that possible but
**if you can reduce the size of the image then it will take less time in loading.**
if you know a little bit about photoshop the is easy to follow these steps:

1. Open the Image
2. Resize According to you to press Ctrl + t button
3. After resizing press Alt+Ctrl+Shift+ s
4. A Window appear and the right side you got the options to manupulate the image in different format like .jpg, .gif etc.
5. Choose .jpg and set the value `60` in `'Quality'` box instead of 100.